# Symfony2 Form becomes invalid on submit when I am trying to append new elements in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have added a button Add section in the form. when a user click that button it opens a prompt window. Prompt window ask for section id  After that it makes ajax call to get the section data from database and creates section form with the respective fields Then I am appending that subform(i.e section form) to the existing form. But when I am submitting the form symfony is throwing error that form is invalid. So basically symfony form does not accept the newly created subform appended to existing form

This is how I am adding button to the form in symfony controller

```
 $formBuilder-> add('new_sections','hidden',array())
  ->add('add','button', array(
        'label' => 'Add Section',

    ))
```

in twig file, Jquery is appending the new fields to the existing form on button Click

```
 $('#form_add').click(
        function(){
            var section_id = prompt("Please enter your Section ID");
            console.log(section_id);
            $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){

                var new_section_form ='' +
                        '<div style="border-style: solid; margin-top: 15px; border-radius: 3px; border-width: 1px; padding: 10px;">'+
                        '<label class="required">'+result['section']['section_id']+'</label>'+
                '<div id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'" class="SectionForms">'+
                 '       <div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_weight'+result['section']['section_id']+'">Weight </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_weight'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][weight'+result['section']['section_id']+']" value="0"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_label'+result['section']['section_id']+'" class="required">label </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_label'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][label'+result['section']['section_id']+']" required="required" value="Text Description v2"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_active'+result['section']['section_id']+'" class="required">Active </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_active'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][active'+result['section']['section_id']+']" required="required" value="1"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_link'+result['section']['section_id']+'">Link </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_link'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][link'+result['section']['section_id']+']"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_events_max'+result['section']['section_id']+'">events_max </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_events_max'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][events_max'+result['section']['section_id']+']"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_events_min'+result['section']['section_id']+'">events_min </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_events_min'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][events_min'+result['section']['section_id']+']"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_module'+result['section']['section_id']+'">module</label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_module'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][module'+result['section']['section_id']+']"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_module_icon'+result['section']['section_id']+'">module_icon </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_module_icon'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][module_icon'+result['section']['section_id']+']" value="icon_generic"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_module_id'+result['section']['section_id']+'">module_id </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_module_id'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][module_id'+result['section']['section_id']+']"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_apicall'+result['section']['section_id']+'">apicall </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_apicall'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][apicall'+result['section']['section_id']+']" value="1"></div>'+
                '<div><label for="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_template_static'+result['section']['section_id']+'">template_static </label><input type="text" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_template_static'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][template_static'+result['section']['section_id']+']"></div>'+

                '<input type="hidden" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_changed'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][changed'+result['section']['section_id']+']" class="changedField" value="2">'+
                 '       <div><button type="button" id="form_'+result['section']['section_id']+'_delete_'+result['section']['section_id']+'" name="form['+result['section']['section_id']+'][delete_'+result['section']['section_id']+']" class="btn-delete">Delete Section No. '+result['section']['section_id']+'</button></div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'


                $('.SectionForms').last().parent().after(new_section_form);
                $('#form_new_sections').val($('#form_new_sections').val()+" "+result['section']['section_id']);

            }});
        });
```

But when I am submitting the form its not entering in form valid block

```
 if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
        // not entering in this block
        }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a token field hidden in the form that is accidentally getting replaced? Is there validation in Symfony2 for this form, and if so, what are the validation rules? Try Form::getErrorsAsString() to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Please post the code that relates to this issue.

Comment: This is how I am adding button to the form in symfony controller

$formBuilder
            -> add('new_sections','hidden',array(

            ))
      ->add('add','button', array(
            'label' => 'Add Section',
            
        ))

Comment: in twig file, Jquery is appending the new fields to the existing form on button Click
$('#form_add').click(
            function(){
                var section_id = prompt("Please enter your Section ID");
              
                $.ajax({url: url, success: function(result){
                    
                    var new_section_form = //some html code


                    $('.SectionForms').last().parent().after(new_section_form);
                    $('#form_new_sections').val($('#form_new_sections').val()+" "+result['section']['section_id']);
                }});
            });

Comment: But when I am submitting the form its not entering in form valid block 
if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
            
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
            // not entering in this block
            }
            }

Comment: @MikelBitson I tried to echo  Form::getErrorsAsString() there is no error in any element of the form. But it is not considering new element added to the form

Comment: Hey Prince, if the $form->isValid is returning false, there are errors. In the else part of this if, try $form->getErrorsAsString();

Comment: Yes i did exactly like that

Comment: Firstly, you should post your code *in your question* so people don't have to guess at solutions. Secondly, you probably just don't have allow add set http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony 2.6 you can silence this error by adding this to your form options:

```
'allow_extra_fields' => true,
```

See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields) for more info

Comment: But I'm using Symfony 2.3.

Comment: I suggest you upgrade, it's not very difficult